# After sending using [RelayCommand] in maui the setter in ViewModel receives truncated string in Maui

Tags: string, mvvm, maui, truncated

After sending using [RelayCommand] in maui the setter in ViewModel receives truncated string in Maui.
Example orginal string:  "https://twit.memberfulcontent.com/rss/9039?auth=m9FZurRandomAuthonumbers6yB"

The value of URL is good here:

```
[RelayCommand]
    async Task Tap(string Url)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tap Sending: " + Url);
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ShowPage)}?Url={Url}");
    }
```

when recieving here URL is truncated:

```
namespace NerdNewsNavigator2.ViewModel;

[QueryProperty("Url", "Url")]
public partial class ShowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region Properties
    readonly TwitService _twitService;
    public ObservableCollection<Show> Shows { get; set; } = new();
    public string Url
    {
        set
        { // value is truncated string from Tap above.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ShowViewModel Recieving url: " + value);
            _ = GetShows(value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Shows));
        }
    }
// Code shortened for brevity
```

Example of passed string:
"https://twit.memberfulcontent.com/rss/9039"
It gets truncated at ?Auth

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong? Or suggestion on a better way to do this? It works fine for string that do not have a ? mark in them. One hundred percent working except on this specific type of string.

I was expecting the string not to be truncated.

Comment: Try UrlEncoding the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to pass data between pages in MAUI:

When you navigate:

```
Dictionary<string, object> query = new()
{
     { nameof(MyModel), myModel }
};
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(MyPage)}", query);
```

When you are navigated:

```
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary < string , object > query)
{ 
    myModel = query[nameof(MyModel)] as MyModel;
}
```

(This solves more than the problem with sanitization)