# Query Parameters in ViewModels in .NET MAUI

Tags: mvvm, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

In the Podcast sample app, I see that query parameters are received directly in view models -- as you can see here: https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-podcasts/blob/main/src/Mobile/ViewModels/EpisodeDetailViewModel.cs

I tried this in my view model but I'm not getting any values i.e. `null`. I currently do it through code behind but I'd like to do it directly in the ViewModel.

Here's my current approach:

MyPage.xaml.cs

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Id), nameof(Id))]
public partial class MyPage: ContentPage
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   MyPageViewModel _vm;
   public MyPage(MyPageViewModel vm)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _vm = vm;
       BindingContext = _vm;
   }

   protected override void OnAppearing()
   {
      base.OnAppearing();
      _vm.InitAsync(Id);
   }
}
```

MyPageViewModel.cs

```
public partial class MyPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   IMyService _myService;
   public MyPageViewModel(IMyService myService)
   {
      _myService = myService;
   }

   public async void InitAsync(string id)
   {
      // Get data
      var data = await _myService.Get(id);
   }
}
```

I'd like to simplify the approach and receive my query parameters directly in my view model.

How do I get my query parameters directly in my view model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass query parameter to .Net Maui ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73293779/how-to-pass-query-parameter-to-net-maui-viewmodel)

Comment: Yes, this works but in the Podcast sample app, I don't see any backing fields or property setters. I'm trying to understand how they do it in the Podcast sample app.

Comment: that sample uses automatic properties

Comment: @Sam, query parameters have no place whatsoever in your Page logic. I suggest this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75231231/6643940

Comment: @H.A.H. Didn't know about this one -- gotta read the docs! Definitely seems advantageous. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use MVVM toolkit [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty#notifying-dependent-commands)

```
[ObservableProperty]
private string? name;

partial void OnNameChanging(string? value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name is about to change to {value}");
}

partial void OnNameChanged(string? value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name has changed to {value}");
}
```